# how to capitalized all words first letter to capital in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a String Extension with my logic.

I checked previously asked questions in stack overflow, but here I want to implement my code rather than following other logic...

here is my effort

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  String capitalize() {
    //to capitalize first letter of string to uppercase
    if(trim().isEmpty)
      return '';
    return "${this[0].toUpperCase()}${this.substring(1)}";
  }


String capitalizeEachWord(){
// looking for good code
}


  String removeExtraSpaces() {
    //to remove all extra spaces between words
    if(trim().isEmpty)
      return '';
    return trim().replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ');
  }



}
```

here is my void main()

```
String str='  i   love  flutter   ';
print(str.removeExtraSpaces().capitalizeEachWord());
// want output : I Love Flutter
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Flutter, but everything with Dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capitalize every word, iterate through them and capitalize first letter and add the rest of the word. You can do so with `split` method. The implementation would look something like this:

```
extension Capitalize on String {
  String capitalize() {
    if (trim().isNotEmpty) {
      final words = removeExtraSpaces()
        .split(' ')
        .map((e) => e[0].toUpperCase() + (e.length > 1 ? e.substring(1) : ''))
        .toList();
      return words.join(' ');
    }
    else return this;
  }
  String removeExtraSpaces() {
    if(trim().isEmpty) return '';
    return trim().replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ');
  }
}

void main() {
  final str = 'i    love   flutter    ';
  print(str.capitalize());
}
```

Comment: Thanks....Solved....upvote pls so that i can upvote others as my ranking is low..and beginner....

Answer (score 1):

You can try my Extension code where you can able to get needed output:

**Extension code:**

```
extension StringExtenssion on String {
  String removeExtraSpaces() {
    return replaceAll(RegExp(r'\s+'), ' ').trim();
  }

  String capitalizeWord() {
    return split(' ').map((word) {
      if (word.isEmpty) return '';
      return '${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.substring(1).toLowerCase()}';
    }).join(' ');
  }
}
```

**Use like this:**

```
 String str = '  i   love  flutter   ';
 print("${str.removeExtraSpaces().capitalizeWord()}");
```

Output: I Love Flutter